# Validate edittext input using databinding library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I am using databinding library. I have a layout which have some edittext for getting basic user input like name, email, password etc. I want to validate these inputs inside the viewmodel on button click. I am a bit confused how to access edittext input on button click inside the view model.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="ViewModel"
        type="me.example.model.LoginViewModel"/>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

  <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:text="Submit"
     android:onClick="@{() -> ViewModel.onSubmitClick()}"/>

</layout>
```

this is the button click method in the view model

```
 fun onSubmitClick(){
    Log.e("Clicked ", "True")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the EditText within the Button's binding expression:

```
 android:onClick="@{() -> ViewModel.onSubmitClick(name.getText().toString())}"
```

One caveat is that snake casing becomes camel casing when doing this, so if your View's `android:id` is `name_edit_text`, you would use `nameEditText.getText()` within the binding expression.

Clicking the Button will then call this method in the ViewModel:

```
fun onSubmitClick(editTextString: String) {
    Log.d("LOG", editTextString)
}
```

Comment: can you show me how to get text, I'm using string and it is giving me error.

Comment: I added a `toString()`. See my edit. EditText#getText() returns an `Editable`, so that was probably causing you an issue.